# Как в php вставить данные из формы в переменную?

Tags: php, переменные, форма

Как в php вставить данные из формы в переменную?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="stat" action="" method="post">
URL: <input name="url" type="text" size="87"><br />
<input type="submit" name="go" value="Отправить"><br /><br />
</form>
<hr />
</body>
</html>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['go']) && $_POST['go'] != null && 
isset($_POST['url']) && $_POST['url'] != null){

$url = $_POST['url'];
echo $url;

}
?>
```